# Getting notified when a question is put on hold

Tags: feature-request

Is it possible in some settings to get a notification when a question is put on hold?

I normally don't look very often on SE even if I have posted a question. My questions normally don't get any answers, and I simply forget about these questions.

Now some of them are put on hold, and I don't even know it. I don't look at my questions daily, because I get notifications when I get a comment or an answer.

I also heard that if you don't improve on-hold-questions your account will be deleted some day or you can't ask any questions any more.

I know that there is a similar question, but it seems to me that the discussion of eight answers was ended about five years ago, so I don't know if this is up-to-date. And it doesn't provide any answer to me either.